# Making angle rotations to a UIImageView but it doesn't make whats expected

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to make a turret that turns to the location thats touched and then shoots the bullet
So far there is no problem but I couldn't figure out why the turret does not face the direction I touched
NOTE: I forgot to tell that it turns but not to the specific location that I touched.
I looked to this sources but they didn't helped
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1823
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018688/rotating-and-moving-a-uiimageview-cocoatouch

here is my code that does the rotation. What am I missing?

```
-(void)update:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    double dx,dy;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    turret.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    bullet.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    bullet.center=turret.center;    
    if ( location.x < 160 )
    {
        dx=turret.center.x-location.x;
        dy=turret.center.y-location.y;
        //if user touched greater than 180
    }
    else if ( location.x > 160 )
    {
        dx=location.x-turret.center.x;
        dy=location.y-turret.center.y;
        //if user touched less than 180
    }
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((atan2(dy,dx)*180/M_PI));
    NSLog(@"%f",atan2(dy,dx)*180/M_PI);
    bullet.transform=transform; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        turret.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        bullet.center=location;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: What does it in fact do - does it rotate at all, and, if so, in what way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe CGAffineTransformMakeRotation uses radians not degrees, so don't multiply the output of atan2(dy, dx) by 180/pi (although you can when you NSLog it if you want it logged in degrees).